# OSError: .pynative/... : file too short

Tags: python

When I try to apply OCRopus (a python-based OCR tool) to a TIFF image, I get the following python error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocropus-nlbin", line 10, in <module>
    import ocrolib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import lstm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/lstm.py", line 32, in <module>
    import nutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/nutils.py", line 25, in <module>
    lstm_native = compile_and_load(lstm_utils)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/native.py", line 68, in compile_and_load
    return ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: .pynative/cccd32009099f8dade0fe6cd205bf188.so: file too short
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocropus-gpageseg", line 22, in <module>
    import ocrolib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import lstm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/lstm.py", line 32, in <module>
    import nutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/nutils.py", line 25, in <module>
    lstm_native = compile_and_load(lstm_utils)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/native.py", line 68, in compile_and_load
    return ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: .pynative/cccd32009099f8dade0fe6cd205bf188.so: file too short
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocropus-rpred", line 7, in <module>
    import ocrolib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import lstm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/lstm.py", line 32, in <module>
    import nutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/nutils.py", line 25, in <module>
    lstm_native = compile_and_load(lstm_utils)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/native.py", line 68, in compile_and_load
    return ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: .pynative/cccd32009099f8dade0fe6cd205bf188.so: file too short
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocropus-hocr", line 8, in <module>
    import ocrolib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import lstm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/lstm.py", line 32, in <module>
    import nutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/nutils.py", line 25, in <module>
    lstm_native = compile_and_load(lstm_utils)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ocrolib/native.py", line 68, in compile_and_load
    return ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: .pynative/cccd32009099f8dade0fe6cd205bf188.so: file too short
```

Since this is as python issue, I haven't tagged OCROpus, should I tag it as well? 
Could it be an Python installation matter? If so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I saw other people having trouble (on diverse matters) with:

> OSError:**[X]**... : file too short

My suggestion is: whatever you are doing, check for hidden directories named [X] in the current directory and delete them.