# File too short when import torch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am connecting to a GPU linux server. I successfully installed anaconda with python 3.8 and pytorch package using the command `"conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch"`. It was successfully installed as well.

However, when I try to import the torch library:

```
import torch
```

I got the following error:

```
OSError: /koti/eeldeeb19/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../../../libcurand.so.10: file too short
```

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: .pynative/... : file too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009710/oserror-pynative-file-too-short)